# How to stop form submissions being saved to database

Tags: solspace-freeform

I'm using Freeform Lite and my client has asked if there's a way they can stop form submissions being saved to database as this causes a headache with the new GDPR regulations. Submissions are emailed to them anyway so they have a record there.

Anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Answer (score 1):

Freeform includes an option inside of Composer interface to disable the storing of data. In Composer view for the form, click on the Form Settings button in Property Editor, then uncheck the checkbox that's labeled *Store Submitted Data*.

That would seem to resolve the question you're asking specifically. However, I would argue that your understanding of the GDPR implications here might not be complete. We actually made a GDPR compliance guide. I would check that out first and let us know if you have any further questions:

https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/docs/gdpr-compliance/

Answer (score 0):

You could accomplish this with a simple custom extension.

You could just do some cleanup post-submission that deletes the record. It would still be written to the database briefly, but it would not be stored. Or you could just save the record with sensitive data removed.

Freeform has lots of hooks:
https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/docs/extension-hooks/

What version of EE and Freeform are you using?